# iOS: Is it possible to get Timezone object from `India Standard Time` string?

Tags: ios, swift, timezone, nstimezone

I know we can get the TimeZone object from the `secondsFromGMT` or the IANA `identifier` or from the abbreviation (like IST).

The thing is from the API, I get the string `Pacific Standard Time`. Which, none of the TimeZone initializers accept.

Is there any way I could instantiate the Timezone with this (such) string?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this approach (adjust according to your needs):

```
let tz = TimeZone(abbreviation: apiString == "Pacific Standard Time" ? "PST" : "GMT")
```

Comment: Basically, I have to prepare the full map of all the existing timezones, and map the API-retured string with the abbreviation?

Comment: So your question does not reflect what you want (...get Timezone object from `India Standard Time`).
 You want the timezone abbreviation given the timezone name for all timezones.
 
You will have to make a structure of names, abbreviations and offsets for each timezone (see wikipedia, for example).
 
 Note that you will have use the `UTC offset` to distinguish between same abbreviations,
 for example `IST – India Standard Time` or
 `IST – Irish Standard Time` or
 `IST – Israel Standard Time`.
 
 Maybe, someone has already done this in Swift, have you search github?